# Javascript setInterval getting shorter every time it runs

Tags: javascript, setinterval

So i've made a function that prints out text letter by letter, shown below.(i know my naming scheme isn't great pls don't make fun. also keep in mind i'm still fairly new to coding so my code might seem a bit odd/inefficient.)

```
var text = document.getElementById("gametext")
var dialog =  "the entire text you want to print out"
var talk = "The whole text gets added here, letter by letter"
var charinc = 0

function talky() {
   setInterval(function(){
   if(charinc < dialog.length){
   talk = dialog.charAt(charinc++);
   text.innerHTML += talk;  
   }
   }, 100);
   charinc = 0
}
```

and i call this function several times throughout my code, setting dialog to whatever it is i want to print, and then calling the function. And it all works fine at first, but every time i run it, it seems that the letters get printed out faster and faster. i'm not really sure what's going on, or how to fix it. i've done a few searches on google but nothing useful came up.

Comment: Why are you initializing `talk` when you're just gonna assign the result from `charAt` to it?

Comment: Every time you call `talky()`, you call `setInterval()` and register a function to be called every 100 milliseconds. You never store the handle from `setInterval`... and never use `clearInterval()` upon it... so, you end up with multiple interval functions running which gives the _appearance_ of a reduced interval period.

Answer (score 6):

The first time you run it, you have one interval running every 100ms.

The second time you run it, you have two intervals, each running every 100ms.

And so on.

Since they share the same variables, you just cause each one to increase the speed of the output by one write every 100ms.

---

Either:

- Call `clearInterval(...)` when you've finished
- Pass the global variables as arguments to `talky` so they aren't shared between the multiple intervals
- Just update the variables instead of calling `talky` again

Comment: Ok, i understand the problem now, but i'm not too sure how i should use clearInterval. should i call it manually every time i want to run talky? should i insert it somewhere inside talky? sorry if i sound like an idiot, but i'm still sorta new to coding.(seems as though i understand some concepts easily, while others, such as intervals, go right over my head.)

Comment: "when you've finished", i.e. as an `else` to `if(charinc < dialog.length){`

Answer (score 3):

`setInterval` will let the function defined by it run every 100ms in your case. If you call this function several times like you say, there will be several intervals running parallel to eachother, which is probably not what you want.

You can clear an existing interval by using `clearInterval` with the id that `setInterval` returns.

e.g.

`var intervalId = setInterval(function() { console.log('hello, world!') }, 100);
 clearInterval(intervalId);`